# how to add an element to each list of a column of a dataframe?

Tags: pyspark

is there any way to add a value to each list of a column of a dataframe?

```
col
['A,'B']
['A']
['F','P','I]
```

now I wanna add `new` to each list:

```
col
['A,'B','new']
['A','new']
['F','P','I,'new']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `array_union` function.

```
df = df.withColumn('col', F.array_union('col', F.array(F.lit('new'))))
```